# Help me in aligning

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, minipage, texstudio

```
\documentclass[]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,dsfont,tikz,mwe,caption,float}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
     \begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}
          \question In the adjoining figure \ref{fig.3}.\thequestion, $\sin\theta=\frac{15}{17}$.  Then $BC=$
          %\choice {85m}\choice{65m}\choice{95m}\choice{75m}
                 \end{minipage} %
    \begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=.60cm,y=.60cm]
 \clip(-5,-1) rectangle (1,5);
 \draw[] (0,0.59) -- (-0.59,0.59) -- (-0.59,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle; 
 \draw (0,0)-- (0,4);
 \draw (0,4)-- (-3.84,0);
 \draw (0,0)-- (-3.84,0);
 \draw [shift={(-3.84,0)}] plot[domain=0:0.81,variable=\t]({1*0.97*cos(\t r)+0*0.97*sin(\t r)},{0*0.97*cos(\t r)+1*0.97*sin(\t r)});
 \draw (-2.82,1.02) node[anchor=north west] {$ \theta $};
 \draw (-3.65,2.91) node[anchor=north west] {$ 85 m $};
 \begin{scriptsize}
 %\fill [] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw (0.34,-0.21) node {$B$};
% \fill [] (0,4) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw (0.22,4.36) node {$C$};
 %\fill [] (-3.84,0) circle (1.5pt);
 \draw (-4.3,-0.29) node {$A$};
% \draw[] (-0.7,0.85) node {$90\textrm{\degre}$};
 \end{scriptsize} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
         \label{fig.3}
    \end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.60\textwidth}
\question In the adjoining figure $\angle ABC=$
%\choice{$45\degre$}{$30\degre$}{$60\degre$}{$50\degre$}{}
\\ (a) fjdkjdjf \quad (b)j fjhijkf \quad (c)nifjdfd \quad (d)jnijffjdkj 
\end{minipage} %
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=.60cm,y=.60cm]
\clip(-3.2,-1) rectangle (5,4.5);
\draw[] (0.42,0) -- (0.42,0.42) -- (0,0.42) -- (0,0) -- cycle; 
\draw (0,0)-- (0,4);
\draw (0,4)-- (4,0);
\draw (0,0)-- (4,0);
%\draw [shift={(4,0)}] plot[domain=2.36:π,variable=\t]({1*0.71*cos(\t r)+0*0.71*sin(\t r)},{0*0.71*cos(\t r)+1*0.71*sin(\t r)});
\draw (-3,2.26) node[anchor=north west] {$ 100\sqrt 3 \;m $};
\draw (1.52,0.08) node[anchor=north west] {$ 100\;m $};
\begin{scriptsize}
%\fill [color=xdxdff] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[] (-0.5,0.26) node {$A$};
%\fill [color=xdxdff] (0,4) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[] (0.16,4.26) node {$C$};
%\fill [color=xdxdff] (4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[] (4.42,0.48) node {$B$};
%\draw[] (0.78,0.5) node {$90\textrm{\degre}$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{questions}


\end{document}
```

Kindly help me in aligning these questions and the figure with suitable environment. And how can I number the figure and how can I refer?
Help me...

**Output**

[image: error file]

Comment: How do you want to align the figures? Left? Right? Center? Where do you want to put the figure numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `[H]` option of the package `float` to position your figures at their exact location. Combine it with a negative value for `\vspace*` to "align" the figure with your multiple choice answers.

Refering to your pictures is done with `\ref` and by placing `\label` inside the figure environment (after the caption).

Also, your tikzfigures can be drawn with way less code:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{questions}
        \question In the adjoining figure (Figure \ref{fig1}), we have $\sin\theta = \frac{15}{17}$. Then $|BC| =\ ?$
        \begin{choices}
            \choice{65m}
            \choice{75m}
            \choice{85m}
            \choice{95m}
        \end{choices}

        \vspace*{-3cm}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \raggedleft
            \begin{minipage}{4.3cm}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \coordinate [label=left:$\scriptstyle A$] (A) at (0,0);
                    \coordinate [label=above:$\scriptstyle B$] (B) at (2.5,2.5);
                    \coordinate [label=right:$\scriptstyle C$] (C) at (2.5,0);

                    \draw (A) -- node[above,rotate=45]{\scriptsize 85m} (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
                    \draw (.5,0) arc (0:45:.5) node at (0.7,0.3){$\theta$};
                    \draw (2.2,0) -- (2.2,0.3) node[above]{$\scriptstyle 90^\circ$} -- (2.5,0.3);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{first triangle}
                \label{fig1}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}

        \question In the adjoining figure (Figure \ref{fig2}), calculate $A\hat{B}C$.
        \begin{choices}
            \choice{$30^\circ$}
            \choice{$45^\circ$}
            \choice{$50^\circ$}
            \choice{$60^\circ$}
        \end{choices}

        \vspace*{-3cm}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \raggedleft
            \begin{minipage}{4.3cm}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \coordinate [label=left:$\scriptstyle A$] (A) at (0,0);
                    \coordinate [label=right:$\scriptstyle B$] (B) at (2.5,0);
                    \coordinate [label=above:$\scriptstyle C$] (C) at (0,2.5);

                    \draw (A) -- node[below]{\scriptsize 100m} (B) --  (C) -- node[left]{\scriptsize $100\sqrt{3}$m} (A);
                    \draw (0.3,0) -- (0.3,0.3) node[right]{$\scriptstyle 90^\circ$} -- (0,0.3);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{second triangle}
                \label{fig2}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i thing this will not solve the problem always

Comment: its not covering the full page horizontally.. means i expect my diagram must be placed in the right end.

Comment: Then use `\raggedleft` instead of `\centering`

Comment: ITS NOT WORKING...

Comment: I edited the code in my answer so your figures are on the right side of the document. It's done by using `\raggedleft` instead of `\centering` and by placing the tikzpicture inside a `minipage` environment to make sure that the caption of the picture is still centered underneath the picture.